On the solutions of $y''=yP(x)$ or $y'+y^2=P(x)$
Are there any general solutions to $y''=P(x)y$? A change of variables $y=e^u$ implies
$y''=(u''+(u')^2)e^u $ and $u''+(u')^2=P(x)$. Therefore, $y''=P(x)y$ reduces to $w'+w^2=P(x)$, but I was not able to solve it (neither did WolframAlpha). If it helps, $P(x)=\frac{Ax^2+B}{(x^2+a^2)^2}$, but I am also interested in general solutions.
Motivation
These differential equation arise during finding a closed-form for the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!n!}x^n
\quad ,\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3n)!}{n!n!n!}x^n
\quad ,\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(6n)!}{n!(2n)!(3n)!}x^n
\quad ,\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n)!}{n!n!(2n)!}x^n.
$$
Alternatively, it would be equally interesting if any of the above summations have closed-forms.

Try: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y%27%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+y%5Bx%5D+%28a++x%5E2+%2B+b%29%2F%28%28x%5E2+%2B+c%5E2%29%5E2%29

The final solution contains associated Legendre polynomials, which are themselves given by some other similar 2nd-order ODEs. Does this mean that the ODEs and the series in the Motivation part of OP do not have closed-form solutions?

Not sure these help, but Sum 1, Sum 2, Sum 3, Sum 4

I would say yes, there is not an elementary solution to this DEQ. I wonder if anything is known about $a, b , c$ (using my notation) that can possibly help matters.

The WolframAlpha's solutions for the summations contain elliptic integrals and generalized hypergeometric functions. I suppose taking there is not an elementary solution to this DEQ is a good enough conclusion. Thank you for your time.

There is $\sqrt{1-4x}=\sum\binom{2n}{n}x^n$, but a similar approach does not seem to apply to the first sum.

Even the simple case of $y'' = xy$ doesn't have a closed form. Anything more complicated than that seems hopeless in general.

For  $a \ne 0 $ we have
$$
\frac{Ax^2+B}{(x^2+a^2)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^{k+1}\left(k A-\frac{(k+1)B}{a^2}\right)x^k
$$

@Cesareo: Where is the $x$ on the RHS?

For general parameters $A, B$ the general solution can be expressed in terms of the Legendre $P$ and $Q$ functions.

I looked up the four coefficient sequences of the sums in the OEIS. The first sum is elementary and the other three can be expressed as ${}_2F_1$'s:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{3n}nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{A005809}(n)x^n=\frac{\cos((1/3)\arcsin\sqrt{27x/4})}{\sqrt{1-27x/4}}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{3n}{n,n,n}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{A006480}(n)x^n={}_2F_1(1/3,2/3;1;27x)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{6n}{n,2n,3n}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{A113424}(n)x^n={}_2F_1(1/6,5/6;1;432x)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{4n}{n,n,2n}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{A000897}(n)x^n={}_2F_1(1/4,3/4;1;64x)$$

The last three summations easily follow from the definition of generalized hypergeometric function, but a closed-form for the first sum is nice.
